# How to increment value of a Column based on previous Row's value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I have two Tables: **User_master** and **Item_master**.

There is a User with **user_id** = 10.

```
|---------|
| user_id |
|---------|
|   10    |
|---------|
```

There are 5 Items with **item_id** = 20 to 24.

```
|---------|---------|------------|
| item_id | user_id | item_order |
|---------|---------|------------|
|   20    |    10   |     0      |
|---------|---------|------------|
|   21    |    10   |     0      |
|---------|---------|------------|
|   22    |    10   |     0      |
|---------|---------|------------|
|   23    |    10   |     0      |
|---------|---------|------------|
|   24    |    10   |     0      |
|---------|---------|------------|
```

There is one more column in **Item_master** that is **item_order(int)**.
I want to place **item_order** = 0 to 4 in all these rows with only single query.

Is it possible?

**EDIT :**

item_id is not supposed to be in order.

For example, instead of 20,21,22,23,24; it could be 20,25,31,47,58.

Comment: A very simple solution would be to subtract 20 from the item_id and use that: `update item_master set item_order = item_id - 20`.

Comment: is {`item_id` `user_id`} guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: @Ic, yes those are the primary keys of respective tables.

Comment: @RAS: Yeah, thought so. That's why I posted a comment and not an answer. It shows however, how important it is to define your constraints when asking a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` window function to assign an increasing number to each row with the same `user_id`.  A subquery is required because you cannot use window functions directly in the `set` clause.

```
update  im
set     im.item_order = im.rn
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by user_id
                                   order by item_id) - 1 as rn
        ,       *
        from    item_master
        ) as im;
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bfb09/3/1)

Answer (score 3):

Extrapolating a little bit and since {`item_id`, `user_id`} is unique in the table, here is a generic solution:

```
UPDATE m
SET item_order = x.new_item_order
FROM item_master m
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT [item_id], [user_id], 
      (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] 
                          ORDER BY [item_id]))-1 AS [new_item_order] 
  FROM item_master
) x ON m.item_id = x.item_id AND m.user_id = x.user_id
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d7d7/1)

This will set the `item_order` column in order of `item_id` for each user, starting at 0.

Comment: @Ic. Thanks for answering but Andomar's answer is much simpler.

Comment: @RAS Yes Andomar's answer will be one step simpler than this one because the join is apparently not necessary

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed you'd want to group by user to generate the number and that item_order column is already there, just needs updating?

```
update IM
    set item_order = t.RowNumber
FROM Item_master IM
INNER JOIN
    (select item_id , user_id , ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY user_id order by item_id ) -1 as 'RowNumber' from Item_master) T
    ON T.item_id = IM.item_id
```